# Print page in same size for all screens

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

maybe this question is too weird or even is off-topic, sorry for that but I have this doubt:

Exists a way to show a HTML page in the same size for all screens when the user types control + p (print page)?

For example my laptop have this screen resolution: 1600x900 and when I type control + p the HTML page look perfect (all in 1 page)!

Problem appears when I use a bigger(page appear in 2 or more pages) or smaller screen(page appear in 1 page but with a lot of blank spaces).

At the moment I tried with @page margins but not work at all, just in some cases, however here is the code:

```
 <style>
    @page :left {
    }
    @page :right {
        margin-top: 0.2cm;
        margin-bottom: 0.2cm;
    }

    body {
        font-size: 9.5px;
    }
</style>
```

PD. I'm using JavaScript, jQuery, HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Control + P means print, right?

Then yes, you should use the media query

```
@media print{
}
```

This a good explanation: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/